# Angular Reactive forms - Default value for controls not working

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I want to have a preselected option on my dropdown list. i set to preSelectedLegalType the value on ngOnInit  but i can't display it.How can i display this value?

My ts file

```
export class BusinessDetailsComponent implements OnInit{
  legalTypes: any = ["Α.A.", "B.B, "C.C", "D.D.", "Ε.Ε"];
  preSelectedLegalType: string = this.stateService.legalEntity.LegalType;


 constructor(private stateService: StateService){
    this.businessDetailsForm = this.createForm();
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.businessDetailsForm.controls['legalType'].setValue(this.preSelectedLegalType, {onlySelf: true});
  }

  createForm() {
return this.fb.group({
  legalType: [this.preSelectedLegalType, [Validators.required]],
  businessName: ['', {validators: [Validators.required]}]
})
}
```

html

```
<select class="form-control custom-select-text" id="legalType" formControlName="legalType" required>
  <option *ngFor="let legalType of legalTypes" [ngValue]="legalType" class="testhover" >{{legalType}}</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: could you log what is the value of `preSelectedLegalType`?

Comment: Use `ng-model="preSelectedLegalType"` in the `select` tag

Comment: @ajuni880 preSelectedLegalType is a string like "Α.A."

Comment: @NikolaosTzimpoulas and in your html do you add the `[formGroup]="businessDetailsForm"` directive?

Comment: Yep, my form working great, i didnt post here the whole form! Just can't display the preselected option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use FormBuilder `control()` method to create controls in the Form as shown below.

```js
createForm() {
  return this.fb.group({
    legalType: this.fb.control(this.preSelectedLegalType, [Validators.required]),
    businessName: this.fb.control('', [Validators.required])
  });
}
```

The first argument of `control()` method takes the initial value, followed by the array of Validators.

More about the `control()` of FormBuilder can be found [here](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder#control).
You can find the complete example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u7rfap) in Stackblitz.

Comment: Thank for your help. I added legalType: this.fb.control(this.preSelectedLegalType, [Validators.required]) but still on my html option is empty

Comment: my HTML: <select class="form-control custom-select-text" id="legalType" formControlName="legalType" required>
            <option *ngFor="let type of legalTypes" value="{{ type }}" class="testhover">{{type}}</option>
          </select>

Comment: Is the default legal type being fetched from an async method (like a HTTP call) ?

Comment: No. i save it on a previous component on a model property using angular service.

Comment: I have shared a sample app in Stackblitz and it works. I guess the value isn't there when you create the FormGroup. Just console log the default legal type before creating the formgroup to check if it is available first.

Comment: On my ngOnInit method i have: this.preSelectedLegalType = this.stateService.legalEntity.LegalType;
    this.businessDetailsForm = this.createForm(); . So i assign the value first to the preSelectedLegalType and after that i create the form. I console log my form after that and the LegalType have the right value!I think the problem maybe is on my html. i will look for it

Comment: As far as I have seen, there is no problem in your HTML template. Just check if you you have the default value before creating the form. Also make sure that you don't have any typos and the default value matches the one in the list. Try console logging before creating form and check.